# Pthreads signal-like pause?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

Is there a way in the pthreads API that I can have one thread instruct either itself or another thread to pause?

By pause, I mean stop executing and stop getting scheduled until another thread signals it to resume.

Comment: Do you want to pause anywhere or at specific points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [pthread / POSIX Thread stack](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pthreads), you may use pthread_kill to send signals to individual threads; but unfortunately that doesnt include "stop", "continue", or "terminate". See the Notes [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_kill)

If you are only interested in pausing the thread; a crafty formula of mutexes and conditional variables are the best way forward.

Comment: yeah David Schwartz, enjoy that bounty ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can use mutexes and condition variables for this purpose.

To tell another thread to pause:

1. Lock a mutex.
2. Set a shared `pause` variable to true.
3. Release the mutex.

To check if you need to pause:

1. Lock the mutex.
2. Check if the `pause` variable is set to true.
3. If not, release the mutex and continue.
4. If so, block on the condition variable and go to step 2.

To unpause a thread:

1. Lock the mutex.
2. Set the `pause` variable to false.
3. Broadcast the condition variable.
4. Release the mutex.

But I have to point out that this is almost certainly not a sensible thing to do. There is no reason you should ever want to pause a thread. Your outer problem is probably something like stopping the process from doing work of a particular type. That should be done by commanding the threads to do other work, not by stopping them from doing *any* work.